# Misaligned vertical table margin

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, margins, overflow

Hopefully I'm not posting a duplicate.
I have the following table:
[image]

I have two problems which I greatly appreciate some help. As seen, the vertical text overflows with the horizontal text (e.g., "Standardized" and "Maturation"). Also, spacing between elements differs (space between "Regulated" and "Standardized" different from space between "Data" and "Fungible".
The code is here: https://pastebin.com/xrGnW3Aa

How can I make this table look like the following, including the vertical margins and spacing between vertical words?

[image]

Thank you very much

EDIT: Source -

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|c|l|l|l}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Asset}} &
  \multicolumn{13}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Trust \\ Establishment\end{tabular}}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}CC-Tx \\ Realization\end{tabular}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Type}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Maturation}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Correctness}} &
  \multicolumn{6}{c|}{\textbf{Decentralization}} &
  \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Channel}} &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \cline{1-18}
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
 &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{} &
   &
   &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\
\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotV{Data}} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Fungible}}} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Non-fungible}}} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{\centering Standardized}}} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Regulated}}} &
  \multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Behavioral}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Formal}}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{User}}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Consortium}}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Trusted Party}}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{On-chain}}}} &
  \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{-3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Off-chain}}}} &
  \multirow{-4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Cross-claim}}} &
  \multirow{-4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1cm}{Escrowed cross-claim}}} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\multirow{-4}{*}{\rotV{Mediate}}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D8E3BB}+} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BF504D}-} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D8E3BB}+} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D8E3BB}+} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D8E3BB}+} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D8E3BB}+} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BF504D}-} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BF504D}-} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BF504D}-} &
  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{BF504D}-} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$} &
  \cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$ &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$} &
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F79545}$\pm$} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide MWE in your question, not in a link which can be after while dead. It should be in form of small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false
            ]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.5 cm}{\raggedright#1}}}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c|}{#2}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcd{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{|c|}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\caption{This is a table}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{15}{C|} }
    \hline
\mcd[5]{\thead{Asset}}  & \mcc[7]{\thead{Trusted Establishment}}   
    &\mcc[3]{\thead{CC-Tx\\ realization}}           \\ \hline
\mcd[3]{\thead{Type}}   & \mcc[2]{\thead{Maturation}} 
    & \mcc[2]{\thead{Correctness}} 
                        & \mcc[3]{\thead{Decentralization}} 
    & \mcc[2]{\thead{channel}}  &   &   &           \\ \cline{1-12}
\RotText{Data} 
    & \RotText{Fungible} 
        & \RotText{Non-fungible} 
            & \RotText{Standardized}    
                & \RotText{Regulated}   
                    & \RotText{Behavioural} 
                        & \RotText{Formal}  
                            & \RotText{User} 
    & \RotText{Consortium}
        & \RotText{Trusted Party}
            & \RotText{On-chain}
                & \RotText{Off-chain}
                    & \RotText{cross-claim}
                        & \RotText{Esscrowded cross-claim}
                            & \RotText{Mediaate}    \\ \hline
\cellcolor{green}{+} 
    & \cellcolor{red}{-} 
        & \cellcolor{orange}{$\pm$} 
            & \cellcolor{green}{+} 
                & \cellcolor{green}{+}
                    & \cellcolor{green}{+}
                        & \cellcolor{green}{+}
                            & \cellcolor{red}{-}
    & \cellcolor{red}{-}
        & \cellcolor{red}{-}
            & \cellcolor{red}{-}
                & \cellcolor{orange}{$\pm$}
                    &  \cellcolor{orange}{$\pm$}
                        & \cellcolor{orange}{$\pm$}
                            & \cellcolor{orange}{$\pm$}
    \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note:
Table is quit wide, so MWE use `geometry` package to define wider text area.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I'm using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables/, which I think does not support tabularx. Any workaround that you know?

Comment: @Rafael, a workaround you can see in my answer.  For nice tables you need to manually tweak tables. Table generators so far cannot compete with humans :-)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might be a solution for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.5 cm}{\raggedright#1}}}


\begin{document}
    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a table:}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Asset}} &
        \multicolumn{8}{c|}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Trusted} \\ \textbf{Establishment}\end{tabular}} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{CC-Tx} \\ \textbf{realization}\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Type}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Maturation}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Correctness}} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Decentralization}} &
        \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Channel}} &
        &
        &
        \\ \cline{1-13}
        \RotText{Data} &
        \RotText{Fungible} &
        \RotText{Non-fungible} &
        \RotText{Standardized} &
        \RotText{Regulated} &
        \RotText{Behavioural} &
        \RotText{Formal} &
        \RotText{User} &
        \RotText{Consortium} &
        \RotText{Trusted Party} &
        \RotText{On-chain} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\RotText{Off-chain}} &
        \RotText{cross-claim} &
        \RotText{Esscrowded cross-claim} &
        \RotText{Mediaate} \\ \hline
        \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+ &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}- &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$ &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34} + &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34} + &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34} + &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34} + &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} - &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} - &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} - &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} - &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$ &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$ &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$&
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$ &
        \cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\newcommand\RotText[1]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{2.5 cm}{\raggedright#1}}}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{A}{>{\centering}m{0.1\textwidth}}


\begin{document}
    

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{This is a table:}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|A|AAA|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Asset}} & 
    \multicolumn{7}{c|}{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\textbf{Trusted} \\ \textbf{Establishment}\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{CC-Tx realization}} \\ \cline{1-12}
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Type}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Maturation}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Correctness}} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Decentralization}} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Channel}} &
    &
    &
    \\ \hline
\RotText{Data} &
\RotText{Fungible} &
\RotText{Non-fungible} &
\RotText{Standardized} &
\RotText{Regulated} &
\RotText{Behavioural} &
\RotText{Formal} &
\RotText{User} &
\RotText{Consortium} &
\RotText{Trusted Party} &
\RotText{On-chain} &
\RotText{Off-chain} &
\multicolumn{1}{A|}{\RotText{cross-claim}} &
\multicolumn{1}{A|}{\RotText{Escrowded cross-claim}} &
\RotText{Mediate}  \tabularnewline  \hline
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$  & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+    & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+    & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{34FF34}+     & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}-   & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$   & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$}       & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$}     & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F56B00} $\pm$     \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Roland, this is really close to what I need. Do you know how can one make the margins the same for all elements (the margins on "Regulated" are bigger than the margins of "Data", and "Fungible", for example)

Comment: @ Rafael I think in your initial question you did not mention, that the space should be equal. Anyway I edited my table version so that the margins are adjusted.

Comment: thank you. This also works.